# JQuery - Drag and drop working but how to disable multi selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I looked into a codepen I want to use for a project; https://jsfiddle.net/6mhndzr5/
When I drag an drop single cards, all is working correct.

But when I click between cards it multi-selects all cards in a column. When positionig this multi-selection outside the columns, I get different errors;

```
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:14925)
    at ua (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:13069)
    at n.fn.init.before (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:14862)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._clear (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js:12:18654)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._clear (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js:6:7987)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js:12:3225)
    at HTMLUListElement.d.complete (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:27958)
    at i (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:27151)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:27914)
    at i (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:26240)
```

I want only single-select to be possible

Is there any way (might be javascript, might be css) to make sure it is not possible to multi-select?
Or cancel this effect?

thx in advance,
Joost

Comment: Change `$(obj + ', .cards').sortable({` to `$(obj).sortable({`. `.cards` is the whole container of `li` in the given example.

Comment: Thanks it works. Only one more problem rises; when you make a column empty now, you can't re-assign a boarditem to the empty column. I tried fixing it with "dropOnEmpty: true" but that didn't work

Comment: Set a `min-height` to your `.draggable`. You cant move stuff in a container if its height is zero. https://jsfiddle.net/zhuLbd6w/